# make d3 link change colour when clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm woking with a family tree using basically this tree layout : http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

And I want to change the colour of link when I click on it, and change it back when click again. 
Here is my code:

```
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .on("click", function(){var nextColor = (this.style.stroke !== "steelblue" ? "steelblue" : "#ccc");
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", nextColor) });
```

It works when I click on the link once, but doesn't change colour when click again. Someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: The code is correct, the error must be somewhere else. Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle/plunkr?

Comment: I solved the problem by changing "steelblue" to "#4682b4" and "#ccc" to "#cccccc"... although I don't understand why... but it works now!